# Using Consolas font on Linux

Tags: debian, fonts

What is the most hassle-free way to install and use the MS Consolas font type in Debian Linux?

Since it doesn't come with the mscorettf package, what could be the way to install it with less commands yet from official(or trustworthy) repos?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The most hassle-free way to install a font that doesn't come prepackaged by your distribution is probably to drop it under `/usr/local/share/fonts` or `~/.fonts`. For this, you need the font file in some unpackaged format, such as plain TrueType (.ttf).**

At least on Debian Wheezy, you will find an XML file /etc/fonts/fonts.conf which provides the system-wide fontconfig configuration. One of the purposes of this is to specify where the system should look for fonts.

Modern Linux systems mostly use TrueType and OpenType fonts, while I think Windows still mainly uses TrueType. So you will have to grab the TrueType font file (.ttf extension) from somewhere trustworthy first. Note that a single font may consist of multiple font files.

Then, place the .ttf file(s) in one of the two directories (depending on whether you want it available system-wide or if you want it available only to you), possibly restart the software in which you plan on using the font (to make it re-scan the available fonts), and the font should just show up in the list of available fonts.

If the font doesn't show up, run `fc-cache -f` to recreate the font cache files, then try again.

I suggest creating subdirectories under either `fonts` directory to keep things organized, but that's a preference, not a requirement by the system.